# Usar variables de una funcion

Tags: python

```
cont=0
loss=0
draw=0
def EntrarDatos():
    global cont
    global loss
    global draw
    NombreRival=(input('Digite el nombre del rival: '))
    GolRival=int(input('Digite los goles del equipo rival: '))
    GolesUnab=int(input('Digite los goles de la UNAB:'))
    Uni='Unab'
    Datos=Uni,GolesUnab,GolRival,NombreRival
    if GolesUnab>GolRival:
        cont+=1      
        print('Partidos ganados: ',cont)
    elif GolesUnab==GolRival:
        draw+=1
        print('Partidos empatados: ',draw)
    else:
        loss+=1
        print('Partidos perdidos: ',loss)
    win=3
    empate=1
    total=(cont*win)+(draw*empate)
    print('Los puntos son: ',total)
    return Datos
```

Necesto usar cont,loss,draw y total en otra funcion pero no se como usar estos valores, con el resultado ya dado en la funcion EntrarDatos(),estos valores estan en una lista dentro de una lista, que cada vez va aumentando asi que tampoco se si puede con los indices, y como seria?

Comment: Cuando hago lo que me indica, al momento de pedir esa opcion me vuelve a pedir las variables de EntrarDatos

Answer (score 1):

Tu función te retorna una tupla, así que al final puedes usar una variable para asignarle la tupla retornada de la siguiente manera:

```
cont=0
loss=0
draw=0
def EntrarDatos():
    global cont
    global loss
    global draw
    NombreRival=(input('Digite el nombre del rival: '))
    GolRival=int(input('Digite los goles del equipo rival: '))
    GolesUnab=int(input('Digite los goles de la UNAB:'))
    Uni='Unab'
    Datos=Uni,GolesUnab,GolRival,NombreRival
    if GolesUnab>GolRival:
        cont+=1      
        print('Partidos ganados: ',cont)
    elif GolesUnab==GolRival:
        draw+=1
        print('Partidos empatados: ',draw)
    else:
        loss+=1
        print('Partidos perdidos: ',loss)
    win=3
    empate=1
    datajuego=cont,draw,loss #otra dupla que almacena los datos que estás pidiendo en tu pregunta
    total=(cont*win)+(draw*empate)
    print('Los puntos son: ',total)
    return Datos, datajuego
```

Fijate que retorna dos valores, las dos son tuplas y las agrupará en una tupla de dos tuplas. Como sabes que tus valores que requieres (const, loss y draw) están en la segunda tupla, entonces puedes tener algo así:

```
requeridos = EntrarDatos()
print(requeridos[1])
```

Estando claro que estas dos líneas de código están fuera de la función.
Entonces si requieres el valor de cada una por separado:

```
cont = requeridos[1][0]
print(cont)
loss = requeridos[1][1]
print(loss)
draw = requeridos[1][2]
print(draw)
```